# Deny pull requests into specific branch in TFS

Tags: tfs, pull-request

I need to deny creating pull requests into specific branch for a certain group of users.

They are already set as a group in TFS, that group has been set "Deny" permission for "Contribute" to that specific branch - however its members are still able to create pull requests.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Users with "Contribute" permission in a branch can push new commits to the branch and lock the branch. This permission doesn't control creating pull requests.

There is no permission to control creating pull requests on branch level, you can only control creating pull requests on Repo level, check the following screenshot:

[image]

You can only use [branch policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies-overview?view=azure-devops) to protect your Git branch, but deny creating pull requests into specific branch is not an option.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, this means we are unable to restrict unwanted changes? I need certain team to work within their own feature branch, and to minimize the risk of creating PR into main branches. They need to be able to merge from main branches, naturally - so it has to be the same repo.